# Gradle: Passing variable from one task to another

Tags: git, variables, groovy, gradle, task

I want to pass a variable from one task to another, in the same build.gradle file. My first gradle task pulls the last commit message, and I need this message passed to another task. The code is below. Thanks for help in advance.

```
task gitMsg(type:Exec){
    commandLine 'git', 'log', '-1', '--oneline'
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    doLast {
       String output = standardOutput.toString()
    }
}
```

I want to pass the variable 'output' into the task below.

```
task notifyTaskUpcoming << {
    def to = System.getProperty("to")
    def subj = System.getProperty('subj') 
    def body = "Hello... "
    sendmail(to, subj, body)
}
```

I want to incorporate the git message into 'body'.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can define an `output` variable outside of the `doLast` method, but in script root and then simply use it in another tasks. Just for example:

```
//the variable is defined within script root
def String variable

task task1 << {
    //but initialized only in the task's method
    variable = "some value"
}

task task2 << {
    //you can assign a variable to the local one
    def body = variable
    println(body)

    //or simply use the variable itself
    println(variable)
}
task2.dependsOn task1
```

Here are 2 tasks defined. `Task2` depends on `Task1`, that means the second will run only after the first one. The `variable` of String type is declared in build script root and initialized in `task1` `doLast` method (note, `<<` is equals to `doLast`). Then the variable is initialized, it could be used by any other task.

Comment: Thanks so much! I totally should have tried that... much appreciated! =)

Comment: Thanks for this great example. Kudos to you, brother!

Comment: If you're browsing, take a look at the example below, which is better.

Answer (score 64):

I think global properties should be avoided and gradle offers you a nice way to do so by adding properties to a task:

```
task task1 {
     doLast {
          task1.ext.variable = "some value"
     }
}

task task2 {
    dependsOn task1
    doLast { 
        println(task1.variable)
    }
}
```

Comment: Great to know another method - thanks! Why should global properties be avoided?

Comment: because it is just to easy too loose the context why a global property was used. by having the variable directly bounded to the task which produces it, it is closer on common OO design I think and easier to track. (just my 2 cents here)

Comment: I see. Cool - thanks again for your time and input =)

Comment: doesnt work with gradle 4.4. Tried but fails. any hints?

Comment: @chaosguru Why does it fail? Btw, in `task1` you can just refer to `ext` instead of `task1.ext`